# Como fazer procedure em MySql com select

Tags: mysql, sql

Gostaria de saber como criar uma procedure que realiza um `select` em diversos campos de uma tabela.

Seria um `select list`, tentei fazer mas não tenho ideia por onde começar.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE prCriarDocente ()
  BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;
    SELECT upkDocente, strProntuario, strNome, strEscolaridade, dtNascimento 
    COMMIT;
  END //
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu acredito que o que você ta querendo fazer é uma view não uma procedure,  a view que seria uma "visualização" de uma query, segue o exemplo:

CRIAR A VIEW:

```
CREATE VIEW [NOME DA VIEW]
AS
SELECT 
    [PASSAR OS CAMPOS]
FROM 
    [TABELAS]
WHERE
    [CONDIÇÕES]
```

CONSULTAR A VIEW:

```
SELECT * FROM [NOME DA VIEW]
```